# Passing array as parameter google maps

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, google-maps-api-3

```
function initialize(markers) {

  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 7,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.4378271,-3.6795367)
  }
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(markers[0],markers[1]),
      map: map,
      title: 'Hello World!'
  });
}

function markers() {

var marker = ["1","2","3","4"];

return marker;
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize(markers());
```

This should create a marker in lat 1 long 2, but it crashes miserably

Some advices?

Comment: have you tried any debugging technique? what have you seen in the debugger?

Comment: i solve a problem to need one more ) and the error says now TypeError: a is null

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It was something about how load functions:

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize(markers()));
```

this method, google load "initialize()" before all, then markers() doesn't exist already.

so if you move to

```
body
```

the script and the markers() to

```
head
```

works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Error: Expected ")"

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize(markers());
```

should be

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize(markers()));
```